# How can I replace a Matrix value with a string from a cell array?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array (c) of strings with some numbers marked with ‘#’, and I have a matrix (data) with the same dimensions (5x6).
If "c" has a number marked with '#' then I want then number in the same location of "data" to be replaced by the string containing the '#'.
For instance the data(1,1) should be '# 2.537'. The output should be similar to the “dataT1_2” cell array generated by the script below. The code code below is working but I think it is a bit clumpsy and novice.

```
c = {
    '# 2.537'    '1.219'      '0.457'    '0.214'    '# 0.120'    '0.245'
    '3.244'      '# 1.400'    '0.649'    '0.515'    '0.207'      '0.075'
    '2.993'      '1.282'      '0.605'    '0.309'    '0.140'      '0.140'
    '3.278'      '1.507'      '0.885'    '0.405'    '0.160'      '0.111'
    '3.691'      '1.474'      '0.650'    '0.316'    '0.180'      '0.155'}

IndexE = strfind(c, '#')

data=[
    0.8147    0.0975    0.1576    0.1419    0.6557    0.7577
    0.9058    0.2785    0.9706    0.4218    0.0357    0.7431
    0.1270    0.5469    0.9572    0.9157    0.8491    0.3922
    0.9134    0.9575    0.4854    0.7922    0.9340    0.6555
    0.6324    0.9649    0.8003    0.9595    0.6787    0.1712]

[row,col] = find(~cellfun(@isempty,IndexE))

temp=strsplit(num2str(data(:)'))
shape=size(data)
temp2 = reshape(temp, shape(1,1), shape(1,2))
dataT1_2=temp2;

for m = 1:length(row)
    temp3(m,1)=strcat('# ',temp2(row(m,1),col(m,1)));
    dataT1_2(row(m,1),col(m,1))=temp3(m,1);
end
```

Comment: Is J.Birch the editor the same person as Birch78 the asker? Having multiple accounts is against the TOS. I have rejected your edit because it seemed to change the meaning of the question. Please edit the question using the account you used to post the question.

Comment: Hi Chris. You are right. I have an old account on my iPhone (J.Birch) but a newer account on my laptop (Birch78). I thought my old account was gone. I will edit my question using the Birch78 and figure out which account to delete afterwards. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to learn how to use logical indexing, such as,

```
>> tmp = cellfun(@num2str,num2cell(data),'uni',false); % convert to strings
>> loc = contains(c,'#')  % get locations of elements with a #
loc =
  5×6 logical array
   1   0   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
>> tmp(loc) = c(loc)  % replace elements
tmp =
  5×6 cell array
    {'# 2.537'}    {'0.0975' }    {'0.1576'}    {'0.1419'}    {'# 0.120'}    {'0.7577'}
    {'0.9058' }    {'# 1.400'}    {'0.9706'}    {'0.4218'}    {'0.0357' }    {'0.7431'}
    {'0.127'  }    {'0.5469' }    {'0.9572'}    {'0.9157'}    {'0.8491' }    {'0.3922'}
    {'0.9134' }    {'0.9575' }    {'0.4854'}    {'0.7922'}    {'0.934'  }    {'0.6555'}
    {'0.6324' }    {'0.9649' }    {'0.8003'}    {'0.9595'}    {'0.6787' }    {'0.1712'}
```

**EDIT**:
Based on your comment, then the 3rd line changes to:

```
>> tmp(loc) = cellfun(@(x)sprintf('# %s',x),tmp(loc),'uni',false)
tmp =
  5×6 cell array
    {'# 0.8147'}    {'0.0975'  }    {'0.1576'}    {'0.1419'}    {'# 0.6557'}    {'0.7577'}
    {'0.9058'  }    {'# 0.2785'}    {'0.9706'}    {'0.4218'}    {'0.0357'  }    {'0.7431'}
    {'0.127'   }    {'0.5469'  }    {'0.9572'}    {'0.9157'}    {'0.8491'  }    {'0.3922'}
    {'0.9134'  }    {'0.9575'  }    {'0.4854'}    {'0.7922'}    {'0.934'   }    {'0.6555'}
    {'0.6324'  }    {'0.9649'  }    {'0.8003'}    {'0.9595'}    {'0.6787'  }    {'0.1712'}
```

**EDIT 2**:
If you're using an older version of MATLAB that doesn't have the function `contains` then you can replace the appropriate line with,

```
>>loc = cellfun(@(x)~isempty(strfind(x,'#')),c);
```

Comment: Hi Phil Goddard, you are absolutely right. Sorry for the confusion. What I need is when a '#' is present in the cell the a '#' should be included in front of the number present number in the matrix. I will edit the question above.

Comment: I really appreciate you help, but i get an error when using the "loc = contains(c,'#')  % get locations of elements with a #" command, the error is:
"Undefined function 'contains' for input arguments of type 'cell'."

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is editing your code (and my example) so that you do not have a variable called `cell`.  If the problem persists I'd then look at your version number, if you are using an older version then it might be that the type of inputs allowed by `contains` has changed over time.

Comment: Hi Phil, I did change the "cell" to "c" but I still get the same error. I am using version R1015b

Comment: `contains` was introduced in R2016b. See above edit for an alternative.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot Phil, it is working like a charm